# Print landing zone status for drone footage

Tags: python, opencv, deep-learning, object-detection, yolo

I am designing a program to detect objects in bird's eye drone images. I have trained the YOLO model with my dataset and the classes I want and it works fine, but I have a shortcoming. What I want is to create a mechanism that checks whether the landing zones are available for 2 classes and how I don't know what to do. I'm using OpenCV. I'm giving a few examples for better understanding.(I have 4 classes
)

In the following image, there are two objects named "UAP" and "İnsan" in the image, and since "UAP" is our landing area, the landing area is available, I should get a feedback called "Landing area is available":

[image: There are two objects named "UAP" and "İnsan" in the image, and since "UAP" is our landing area, the landing area is available, I should get a feedback called "Landing area is available"]

In the other image, the object named "İnsan" rests on the region named "UAP" and I should get a feedback called "Landing area is not suitable":

[image: In the other image, the object named "İnsan" rests on the region named "UAP" and I should get a feedback called "Landing area is not suitable".]

I want the same feedback that will apply to the "UAP" class to be valid for the "UAİ" class:

[image: I want the same feedback that will apply to the "UAP" class to be valid for the "UAİ" class.]

If you can post a directive or document it would be more helpful because I want to understand the principle

My experimental half OpenCV code is here

```
import numpy as np
import cv2

# step 1 - load the model

net = cv2.dnn.readNet('best.onnx')

# step 2 - feed a 640x640 image to get predictions

def format_yolov5(frame):

    row, col, _ = frame.shape
    _max = max(col, row)
    result = np.zeros((_max, _max, 3), np.uint8)
    result[0:row, 0:col] = frame
    return result

image = cv2.imread('datasets/Test/frame_014348.jpg')
input_image = format_yolov5(image) # making the image square
blob = cv2.dnn.blobFromImage(input_image , 1/255.0, (640, 640), swapRB=True)
net.setInput(blob)
predictions = net.forward()

# step 3 - unwrap the predictions to get the object detections 

class_ids = []
confidences = []
boxes = []

output_data = predictions[0]

image_width, image_height, _ = input_image.shape
x_factor = image_width / 640
y_factor =  image_height / 640

for r in range(25200):
    row = output_data[r]
    confidence = row[4]
    if confidence >= 0.4:

        classes_scores = row[5:]
        _, _, _, max_indx = cv2.minMaxLoc(classes_scores)
        class_id = max_indx[1]
        if (classes_scores[class_id] > .25):

            confidences.append(confidence)

            class_ids.append(class_id)

            x, y, w, h = row[0].item(), row[1].item(), row[2].item(), row[3].item() 
            left = int((x - 0.5 * w) * x_factor)
            top = int((y - 0.5 * h) * y_factor)
            width = int(w * x_factor)
            height = int(h * y_factor)
            box = np.array([left, top, width, height])
            boxes.append(box)

class_list = []
with open("config.txt", "r") as f:
    class_list = [cname.strip() for cname in f.readlines()]

indexes = cv2.dnn.NMSBoxes(boxes, confidences, 0.25, 0.45) 

result_class_ids = []
result_confidences = []
result_boxes = []

for i in indexes:
    result_confidences.append(confidences[i])
    result_class_ids.append(class_ids[i])
    result_boxes.append(boxes[i])

for i in range(len(result_class_ids)):
    
    box = result_boxes[i]
    class_id = result_class_ids[i]

    cv2.rectangle(image, box, (0, 255, 255), 2)
    cv2.rectangle(image, (box[0], box[1] - 20), (box[0] + box[2], box[1]), (0, 255, 255), -1)
    cv2.putText(image, class_list[class_id], (box[0], box[1] - 10), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX, .5, (0,0,0))
    print(box,class_id)
    if class_id >= 2:
        print("İniş alanı tespit edildi")
    elif class_id <= 1:
        print("İniş alanı değil")
cv2.imwrite("Saving/image.png", image)
cv2.imshow("output", image)
cv2.waitKey()
```

Comment: so... you want to test whether one box is overlapping/inside another box? then just do that.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Yes, this is exactly what I want but how do I do it?

Comment: assume that you have two boxes. calculation is simplified by taking one dimension at a time (x, then y). along one dimension, the task is calculating the overlap of two intervals. intervals [a0,a1] and [b0,b1] overlap if a0 < b1 and b0 < a1. now do that for both x and y coordinates and you're done.

Comment: IoU (intersection over union) or Jaccard index